# Jquery, create table tag with custom ID, then later refer to that ID and append new tags to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

So essentially I want to append a < table> tag to < body> with a custom ID and then later in my code refer to the table with the custom ID and append < tr>, < td>, or < th> to it.

Here's an example:

```
dataHold = data[1].split("@")[1]; //just imagine this as "yahoo.com"

                if( !hold.includes( dataHold ) )
                {
                    $("body").append
                    (
                        "<table id='"+dataHold+"'>"+
                            "<tr>"+
                                "<th>"+dataHold+"</th>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                        "</table>"
                    );

                    $( "#"+dataHold ).append
                    (
                        "<tr>"+
                            "<td>"+data[1]+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[2]+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[3]+"</td>"+
                        "</tr>"
                    );
                }
```

It does append the < table> tag, but for some reason the < tr> tag appending doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: the ".com" part was screwing it up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code is fine, so the problem is with your variables or lack of inclusion of jQuery. Ensure that you have jQuery loaded, and that your three variables (`hold`, `data` and `dataHold`) actually resolve. Don't forget that `hold` is **not** supposed to include `dataHold` for the `if` condition to be entered.

The following snippet shows this working as expected (with all variables set correctly):

```js
const hold = data = [2, 3, 4, 5];
const dataHold = 1;

if (!hold.includes(dataHold)) {
  $("body").append(
    "<table id='" + dataHold + "'>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<th>" + dataHold + "</th>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</table>"
  );

  $("#" + dataHold).append(
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + data[1] + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + data[2] + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + data[3] + "</td>" +
    "</tr>"
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ahhhhh, I see the problem. My examples were stuff like yahoo.com, and apparently the ".com" was messing it all up.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine when isolated to this snippet:

```js
var dataHold = "testId";
var data = ["foo", "bar", "carrots", "broccoli"];

$("body").append(
  "<table id='" + dataHold + "'>" +
  "<tr>" +
  "<th>" + dataHold + "</th>" +
  "</tr>" +
  "</table>"
);

$("#" + dataHold).append(
  "<tr>" +
  "<td>" + data[1] + "</td>" +
  "<td>" + data[2] + "</td>" +
  "<td>" + data[3] + "</td>" +
  "</tr>"
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ensure that you have correctly included the jQuery library before using the jQuery selector function ('$'). Also, use the built-in debugger in your favorite browser to ensure that the values of `dataHold` and `data` are exactly what you expect them to be. If they are `null` or `undefined` you may get errors in the string concatenation resulting in your row not being appended.

Comment: ahhhhh, I see the problem. My examples were stuff like yahoo.com, and apparently the ".com" was messing it all up.